# Accessing CRC (OpenShift) on a remote server: "openshift crc ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused"

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ssh-tunnel, crc

I ask you for help because I was unable to access the OpenShift web console, installed in a VM (CentOS), from my pc (Ubuntu).

I am not an expert on linux, so please excuse me if I make any mistakes in exposing the problem.

I followed these steps:

1. I successfully accessed the shell of the VM via SSH (`ssh myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 8822`).
2. I successfully installed CRC on VM following this guide: https://crc.dev/crc/#installation_gsg.
3. I added at the end of my computer's etc/hosts file the following line: `127.0.0.1 oauth-openshift.apps-crc.testing console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing downloads-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps-crc.testing canary-openshift-ingress-canary.apps-crc.testing`
4. I tried to access the web console of Openshift via SSH with this command: `ssh -L 443:console-openshift-console.apps-crc.testing:443 myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` (same address as in point 1). But I got the following error message: `ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection refused`. If it helps, by running the same command with `-v` flag, I get: `debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files`.

What could be the problem? Did I do something wrong or did I forget any configuration to do? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you add those hosts entries in step 3 to point to your local machine?

Comment: @Seth Sorry, you're right. I just replaced that address with the address I used in the SSH commands. However, launching the SSH command again to access the OpenShift console, I still get the same error. It is strange that the first SSH command works, while the second does not.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't follow the official guide, as that forces you to open ports (and I can't), so I'm using this alternative approach with an SSH tunnel, but I keep getting this error.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you're trying to use port 443 while in your first command you're using the non default port 8822 instead of 22. So you likely need to adjust for port 8822 in step 4.